# What is “Quest 24” in the Dark Tower adventure?

Tags: published-adventures, adnd-1e

In room 1-24 of the Dark Tower adventure (the Goodman Games reprint of the original), the module states that Verus Vorum will ask the adventures to undertake Quest 24. The text is curiously bold, but I can’t find any reference to it elsewhere. What does Quest 24 refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That reference is in the original printing. When I first ran the adventure, which was probably in 1980, I had Verus send them to room 2-24 to assist Hargrove. It doesn't make a lot of sense, but he is crazy.

I suspect, but cannot prove, that the reference is meant to be to a list of quests that was cut from the module, and the reference wasn't cleaned up in copy-editing. Judges Guild didn't have terribly high standards in 1980.